# How to get a question re-opened quickly?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderators, vote-to-reopen

Question in mind: [Algorithm to partition a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334292/algorithm-to-partition-a-number)

The OP asked an unintelligible question that was quickly closed. However, the comments between the OP and other users soon made the question clear; at which point, I edited the already closed question. It's now a worthy question.

Sadly, it's still closed and not getting any attention, so I have no idea how to get the question re-opened.

I admit that this is partly my fault for voting to close the question, and I'll try to take a bit more time before doing so in the future. However, the general question remains: How do I get a question re-opened after a clarifying edit?

Why is this important? Well, the OP wants to repost the same question, with better wording; that will just clutter up SO, and it is not the solution.

Is there a canonical way to handle situations such as this one?

Comment: Good question - is it possible to mod-flag stuff for reopening? Can mods do that?

Comment: @Pekka Yes[.](http://example.com)

Comment: @Matthew ah, cool. Side note, the careers link in your profile is broken

Comment: @Pekka More like [Careers is broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114289/my-public-careers-profile-is-private).  Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention and explain that it was edited and is now a suitable question.

Comment: [(Shamless plug) See also this suggestion for a more community-driven method.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138814/getting-your-question-reopened/138819#138819)