# My public Careers profile is private

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When logged in, I can go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/matthewryanread and view my profile no problem.

When logged out, I get this:

> #### Page Not Found
>
> Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!
>
> If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us.

This is despite the fact that http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/publish says:

> **public view**            published
>
> Your profile is **currently public** at /matthewryanread

[Pekka can't see it either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114286/how-to-get-a-question-re-opened-quickly#comment-297316).  I hope this hasn't been broken for long....

Comment: I can't see it either, even when logged into Stack Exchange.  However, I don't have an account on Careers. Could this be an issue with the definition of "Public"?

Comment: @Kevin I have a careers account and am logged in, but can't see Matthew's profile.

Comment: Yup, we’ve confirmed the issue, stand by…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up, there was a bug that was causing public profiles not to appear, um, publicly. Please try it again and let us know if any issues.

Comment: Seems to work now. At least I can see the profile and I'm not logged in.

Comment: Works for me too now, thank you.

Comment: Seems to be broken again. When editing profile, selecting "public view" and hitting button "make profile public" nothing happens. (Or to be exact, the browser sends POST without the public URL I specified and the POST does nothing but redirect to the same page again.)