# Careers profile public status will not become public

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs, privacy

I know that there a couple of [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114289/my-public-careers-profile-is-private) regarding this issue, but they are marked as fixed - but it isn't.

To clarify: my profile is private (the default), so I go to 'privacy settings' and hit the 'make my profile public' button, a throbber briefly appears and then a green tick with a 'done' replaces it.  There is no save button so I leave the page.  But the 'privacy settings' status on the right of my profile still says 'private', and if I go back into the 'privacy settings' the button still says 'make my profile public'.

Comment: What would the URL to the public profile be? Did you test that URL from a browser not logged in on Careers 2.0? It could be that something is being cached, showing you the old 'private' state. Trying to access the public profile would confirm or deny that hypothesis.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Bloody hell, the separator between the 'Public Status' and `Public URL` sections made my brain ignore it.  Now I've entered a public URL it works fine!

Comment: Cool, so it's a caching bug; Careers 2.0 should signal that the copy you have in your browser is no longer fresh. Your profile does become public, it's just that the status page doesn't show it for you. A force-refresh (Ctrl-F5 or similar) should solve that part.

Answer (score 6):

A profile can only be public if it has a URL, so this is a two-step process, as described in the comments. If you mark yourself public, the browser allows you to then enter a URL, but no data on the server is changed until a valid URL is entered. The UI should be changed to indicate this relationship.

Update: this change has been made. Clearer now?