# Questions closed by non-related users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

I see it every day. Questions gets closed by three or four users who are not related to that topic or tag. They find "marked dupe in `Review` section" and start the race to earn gold badges.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811007/how-can-i-get-date-of-a-coming-day-objective-c/15812383#15812383), this is not dupe, and even marked dupe to a question which does not provide an answer either.

And we can clearly see the profiles for all five users, three were not supposed to vote as they don't look like any near to [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_%28Apple%29), [Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29), [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C), [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X), etc.

And then we will asked in such case vote to reopen. But I think the percentage of reopened questions are very much less.

Should any restriction be made that, users having XX reputation points on a tag can close a question tagged with the same?

Comment: Why is that question *not* a duplicate?

Comment: Even the OP says that the question is essentially a duplicate, but that he does not understand it...why is this not a dupe? Besides that, experience in a tag in many cases has little to do with the ability to see whether or not a question should be closed. It helps, but is not always required.

Comment: Well one question refers to `monday` and the other talks about `saturday`.

Comment: The fundamental logic would still be the same, though, @JonW. Do we really want a question for every day of the week? (Still can't tell if people are being sarcastic on Meta or not.)

Comment: @CodyGray I'm pretty sure that was tongue-in-cheek. Either that or my humour detection is off.

Comment: Related, including the proposal of considering tag scores in casting close votes: [Was this question closed improperly? Possible improvements to the close/reopen process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146593)

Comment: "3 were not supposed to vote" - can you provide us with an authoritative link to support this claim? TTBOMK there is _no such rule_. Also, many people can judge whether the duplicate-mark is correct. In this case, it clearly is.

Comment: Besides "don't _look_ any [where, red.] near to ios,..." is flawed/subjective as well. Just because I don't answer Perl or Java questions regularly, doesn't mean I'm not qualified to read them.

Comment: As one of the people who voted to close I have to say that it was a difficult decision - and I also had a feeling that it would be controversial. It involves the application of not one but _two_ parallel notions: That "upcoming" and "next" are the same concept, programmatically speaking, and that an algorithm working on one weekday should work on another one, too. And even if I mostly roam the cocoa tag, I believe that this line of thinking actually is language-agnostic.

Comment: Sorry for late reply...went for lunch. This question is closed, Thats Good. But reason Duplicate!! Even the linked question is not solved. you are linked to Apple Documentation. So for any question should we link to "Google.com"? As all answers can be find, modified, enhanced from there.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: So post your answer there. Delete the answer on the dupe and re-post it on the other one.

Comment: *"But reason Duplicate!! Even the linked question is not solved"* ... so what is your problem here? That it's not a duplicate, or that the duplicate doesn't have an answer? If it's the latter, give the dupe an answer. Or let the OP of the closed question award a bounty on the duplicate. All that does not mean that the closure was improper.

Comment: Now, i answered the question that was linked as dupe :)

Answer (score 10):

You need not be knowledgeable in a tag to close a post. When I nominated myself(not a chemistry student/chemist) as a moderator for [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/), I was told that "you need not know much about the topic to moderate". That applies to closing as well -- it is generally obvious if a question is too localised, not a real question, or not constructive. Off topic generally isn't hard as well. Regarding duplicates -- this is usually obvious as well.

A post should be phrased in a way such that it is obvious that it isn't a duplicate (or any other close reason). If a post gets closed as a dupe, then edit it to make the differences clear. It will probably get reopened then.

In your specific case "I'm not able to understand this" doesn't make it not a dupe. It just means that the other question needs better answers, which you can provide. (or bounty it)

Note that there is the option to filter by tag in the close queues. The robo-reviewers don't use it though.

Comment: Keeping in mind that the objective here is to share quality information, that modus operand-us should apply to the moderation. Means, responding with up/down, closed ect. must be accompanied with quality input/feedback. It is to easy referring to the standard text of read the FAQ dummy. If you do not have the time to understand the issue at hand, do not use the close/off topic tools.

Comment: @Benalmadena: Well, the FAQ is there for a reason, to make it so that folks don't have to type the same thing over and over again. Same goes for the close banners -- they really should be sufficient. (There are some upcoming major improvements to the close banners that will make this more complete). That being said, I generally write a specific comment on posts I close.

Comment: I wish all would do the same as you, in been specific to why the action was taken, as the generic FAQ is to generic. It would be interesting to track how many users actually go and read the FAQ.

Comment: @Benalmadena: [ask] is a better place to link to. Remember, the close banner explains a lot as well.